# Stop iframe loading gives undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a script that appends several iframes (8 as an example) into the body:

```
image_iframe[sequential number 1-8] = $('<iframe />');
image_iframe[sequential number 1-8].appendTo('body');
```

When I try to stop images in specific iframes from loading:

```
if(window.stop !== undefined) {
      image_iframe[2].contentWindow.stop();
}
else if(document.execCommand !== undefined) {
      image_iframe[2].contentDocument.execCommand("Stop", false);
}
```

I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stop' of undefined

**How can I fix this?**

---

[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LwHUZ/7/) with the original code. Just click the 'Next' button a few times to reproduce the error. It is based on [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amirshim/6vL4N/) from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926215/cancel-single-image-request-in-html5-browsers) which works fine.

I did some searches and found these two questions but not sure if it's the same problem:

1. [I get an undefine error in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167460)
2. [how to correctly stop the transport inside an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435686/how-to-correctly-stop-the-transport-inside-an-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

`image_iframe[index]` is a jQuery element. To get `contentWindow`, you will need to get the iFrame DOM element first. Suggest change

```
// from
image_iframe[this - 3].contentWindow.stop(); 

// to
image_iframe[this - 3].get(0).contentWindow.stop();
```

Comment: I did the change and while it did remove the error, it still doesn't run. The images are still being loaded (checking the network tab). Replacing frame.contentWindow with window.stop(); works fine but it stops all images not just the specified iframes.